# MySQL DB structure, need clarification

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema

I'm designing a website in which you can upload games with a description, etc, and store their rating. I am the only one who can provide a rating, so I won't need a second DB for that.

However, there will be indefinite rounds of competitions, so I want to store the Round # in a column in the DataBase. The other requirement is that each round has it's own information, so I'll be making a second table with a Round_Number, then other fields like Description, Due Date, etc.

So this is my current DB schema idea:

```
Entries ( Comp #, Entry # AutoInc, Password, 
    Entry Date, Author Contact, Description, Screenshot, Website )
Competitions ( Comp #, Theme, Entries, Start Date, Finish Date, Prize )
```

So Entries can left join Competitions on Comp # to get extra information about its competition. Does these seem most efficient? There is no account system (or users table), each entry just gets its own password for editing.

Comment: Can one entry have more than one competition? I assume yes. Can one competition be for multiple entries? I assume no. If my assumptions are correct, I would remove the Comp # from the Entries table and change Entries on the Competitions table to Entry.

Comment: Oops, I should have mentioned, entries is the AMOUNT of entries. Each competition can have multiple entries, but each entry can only be for 1 competition. I track the amount of entries so that I don't have to do count's later on when I want to track the popularity of my comps.

Comment: Oh, okay...so "Entries" are rounds. If that's the case, the structure looks good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think this through further. You could potentially have different screenshots for different Entries and competitions. You might as well define a relational schema and add user accounts for authentication purposes. Define three tables:

`CREATE TABLE USERS_T 
(
 account_id number,
 username varchar,
 password data_type,
 author varchar,
....
)`

`CREATE TABLE COMPETITIONS_T
(
 comp_id number,
 description varchar,
 theme varchar,
 #entries number- not needed, just count by id in ENTRIES_T table
 start_date date,
 finish_date date,
 prize varchar,
...
)`

`CREATE TABLE ENTRIES_T
(
 account_id number,
 comp_id number,
 entry_date date,
 descr varchar,
 screenshot blob,
 website varchar,
 ...
)`

> Each competition can have multiple entries, but each entry can only be for 1 competition.

Add a primary key on the ENTRIES_T table: `PRIMARY KEY (account_id, comp_id)`

You could even take this further, define a themes table, comments table, etc. I think you'll get the idea. Hope this helps. Goodluck!

Comment: Is it a good idea to store the screenies as blobs? How would I output them? Is there a benefit over storing a URL to the screenshot?

Comment: It's purely your discretion, I was only using that as an example. I would say, if you have the space available, make it a blob. I always see sites with external images are referenced and they leave giant X's all over the place, external links go dead eventually. Looks cleaner when you can serve the data yourself, if you have the resources.

Comment: This is true. I'm just wondering if there's benefits to accepting their uploaded images and storing them locally as files, or as blobs. The files are easier to server, I know that for sure, but I guess the blobs could be more secure?

Comment: Yes, filesystem would be just as adequate or better for some cases. Storing the image on the filesystem would definitely take some load off the database, performance varies across platforms, some more advantageous than others. Either way, the bandwidth difference would be marginal if loading from the same server, if loading from the same server. Are you connect to the db directly or using a SOA? What technology are you using to serve your website? PHP, JSP, Servlets, Spring, etc..

Comment: PHP with MySQL. I would always appreciate a little bit of security in my images in case I want some only visible to certain users.. So I might store them in my DB.

Comment: Avoid storing the images in BLOBs. FILE systems are quite good at serving FILES (there's a hint in the name). If you want to secure the files you could still serve them via PHP, although I would advise against this unless security is paramount. Most requirements can be satisfied by renaming the files using random file names - a hash of the image name and current time. And then use the first two groups of six chars from the hash to define the path. Something like bb6bc0df9ec9ad2c0253b1b6f465670a.jpg in /images/bb6bc0/df9ec9/bb6bc0df9ec9ad2c0253b1b6f465670a.jpg